# "community_engine (>= 0) ruby depends on paperclip (~> 2.4.3) ruby" ... I'm using paperclip 3.4.1

Tags: paperclip, communityengine

Trying to get the community engine gem/plugin up and running. Getting error:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "paperclip":
  In Gemfile:
    community_engine (>= 0) ruby depends on
      paperclip (~> 2.4.3) ruby

```
paperclip (3.4.1)
```

What do I do if a gem requires/depends on an OLDER version of the paperclip gem? I would guess I'd only have problems if my version was not up to date. Do I need to downgrade my paperclip gem? Looks like the only other version available is 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing an older version of the Gem like this:

```
sudo gem install paperclip -v 2.4.3
```